# Convert a string array into php array object

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP string array that I would like to convert into a PHP array object.

```
string ->

"Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 315428396
            [title] => Luke Heith
            [link] => somelinks
            [rights] => Array
                (
                    [0] => update
                    [1] => view
                    [2] => grant_view
                    [3] => delete
                    [4] => comment
                    [5] => add_task
                    [6] => subscribe
                    [7] => grant
                    [8] => add_file
                    [9] => add_conversation
                    [10] => rate
                )"
```

Solution a PHP object array. Does someone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Cast it into object. (object)$yourArray

Answer (score 2):

That format is a debugging output format only. It is not possible to 100% convert this back into an actual array; you will always find edge cases where the input will represent ambiguous values. There's also no function to convert this back into an array; you'd have to write one yourself, which is something of an ambitious project.

In short: use a format which can actually be deserialised (like JSON or [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)), this one cannot.